# Use preamble to put all descriptions in a tcolorbox

Tags: lists, tcolorbox, description

I want to style all my `\begin{description}` elements with a `\begin{tcolorbox}`. As my code is autogenerated from pandoc, I do not want to edit the `.tex` code within the body of the document. How do I add `TeX` code to the preamble to "rewrite" all description environments so that they are placed in a `tcolorbox` environment? Effectively resulting in this:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{description}
\end{description}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: Can you give feedback to the provided solution please?

Comment: Feedback provided. It's a great solution, and better than my use of `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` package allows a redefinition of existing environments to be put into a `tcolorbox` inside using `\tcolorboxenvironment`.

This is preferably done in the preamble and is precisely what the O.P. requests, however, I can't test this with `Pandoc`.

This example shows the usage for the `description` environment and just adds some `tcolorbox` keys for eye-candy. If the `description` environment should 'survive' as is, a `\newenvironment{mydescription}` as wrapper is given as well, but commented out.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%\newenvironment{mydescription}{\begin{description}}{\end{description}} % Use 
%\tcolorboxenvironment{mydescription}{enhanced jigsaw, colback=yellow,sharp corners, drop shadow}
\tcolorboxenvironment{description}{enhanced jigsaw, colback=yellow,sharp corners, drop shadow}



\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
\end{description}


\end{document}
```

[image]